# How do I write ${2}^{i}$ in polar form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I haven't been given any extra information so I'm not sure if this is already considered polar form. Here is how I went about it.

${2}^{i} = ({\frac{2}{e}}\cdot{e})^i = {({\frac{2}{e}})^i}\cdot{e^i}$

$\implies r = {({\frac{2}{e}})^i}$ and  $\phi = 1$

Giving the polar form  as ${({\frac{2}{e}})^i} \cdot (\cos{1} + i\sin{1})$

My intuition tells me this isn't right. I'd appreciate any pointers here thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$${ 2 }^{ i }={ e }^{ i\ln { 2 }  }=\cos { \left( \ln { 2 }  \right) +i\sin { \left( \ln { 2 }  \right)  }  } $$

Comment: While your calculation is correct, $(\frac 2e)^i$ isn't a real number,  as is required. ..